# CEF - some font icons not visible when using Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: extjs, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

We are hosting CEF in a WPF application using CefSharp for one of our applications, whose UI is built with ExtJs 6.7.0. Everything seems to work fine, except some font icons are not visible as you can see in attached screenshots:

[image: Font icon not visible]

[image: Another example]

We are using the latest stable version of CefSharp from NuGet. Following is sample css for the clear icon that works perfectly on the regular browsers:

```
.x-cleartrigger .x-icon-el:before {
    content: 'clear';
}
```

Can somebody please assist with why the font icons are not visible when opening the application in CEF using CefSharp?

PS: Font-Awesome icons are working perfectly but other icons aren't.

Comment: The only issue I'm currently aware of is https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2858/fonts-not-loading-look-wrong-on-windows-7 in future please specify the exact version you are using. When I release 84 tomorrow you won't be using the latest and bugs are often version specific.

Comment: I'd also suggest testing with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and make sure the problem reproduces there, it's possible that it's not font related at all.

Comment: @amaitland sorry, I should have provided the versions upfront. Here they are: Chromium Version: 83.0.4103.106; CefVersion: r83.4.2+gc8d4f85+chromium-83.0.4103.106; CefSharp version: 83.4.20.0. My machine is Win 7 x64 but also tried on a Win 8 x64 machine with same results. The referenced Cef bug does look related but I wonder why Font Awesome works then?

Comment: @amaitland And yes, the issues reproduces with CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf and CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms too.

Comment: If you are using Win7/8 then it's likely the same bug. All my machines are Win10 so it's not something I've experienced myself.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the lines starts from "local" (example for font-family: 'Material Icons')

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: /* local('Material Icons'),
    local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), */
    url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
    url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```